# Cache enabled or not?

Tags: http, caching

I am in doubt if I have my cache enabled. It thought I did, but Google Speed Test tells me it's not and so does the 'seositecheckup'-test. These are the HTTP Headers:

```
    HTTP/1.1 200 OK 
Date: Tue, 13 May 2014 15:33:37 GMT 
Server: Apache/2.2.26 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.26 OpenSSL/1.0.1e-fips mod_auth_passthrough/2.1 mod_bwlimited/1.4 FrontPage/5.0.2.2635 
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.24 
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT 
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0 
Pragma: no-cache 
Set-Cookie: TCT_SESS=412bfe220023a4bf9b1233f24748796b; path=/; domain=.asecret.nl 
Cache-Control: max-age=86400, public 
Vary: Accept-Encoding 
Content-Encoding: gzip 
Content-Length: 14540 
Connection: close 
Content-Type: text/html
```

Both the expires_module and the headers_module are loaded and in WHM in my pre-main-include (should put the text at the top of the httpd.conf) I have this:

```
# 1 DAY
<FilesMatch "\.(html|htm|php|cgi|pl|css|js)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=86400, public"
</FilesMatch>

# 1 MONTH
<FilesMatch "\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|swf)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2630000, public"
</FilesMatch>
```

I'm confused, is it enabled, or is it not?

Comment: Looks like you have a dupe `Cache-Control` which is setting `no-cache`, too.

Comment: `Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT ` is a clear "please do not cache this" instruction.

Comment: Thanks, getting that confirmed puts me on the quest of finding the cause.